# Why is Jorah Mormont called Ser when he’s from the North?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Jorah Mormont is from the North (from Bear Island) and they are supposed to worship the old gods.

Being knighted requires a Septon and the Northeners don't believe in Septons, I guess. I thought knighthood was mostly in the rest of Westeros.

Comment: You are correct in your observation. This is precisely the reason why there are so few knights in the North and in Iron Islands, the lack of faith in the Seven and their religion. But given that a religious ceremony is merely customary, not obligatory there are a few knights in both Northmen and Ironmen

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Knighthood doesn't always require to follow the Faith of the Seven, all that is required is another knight to hear you swear your vows to the Seven.

> Knighthood is intimately tied to the Faith of the Seven, and the ideal of knighthood is to be not only an honorable warrior but a devout follower of the Seven.
>
> Eddard Stark himself was not a knight, because he proudly continued to worship the Old Gods of his ancestors, yet still a great warrior. Sometimes, however, **a soldier who *does not* follow the Faith of the Seven may nonetheless be rewarded for exemplary service with the title of knighthood by a lord who does worship the Seven**. Examples are Ser Rodrik Cassel and Ser Jorah Mormont, both of the North.
> <sup><sub>**— *Knighthood*, Game of Thrones Wiki ([source](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Knighthood))**</sub></sup>

Note that though the wiki seems to imply that only soldiers can be knighted, any man can either buy knighthood or earn it with a great deed (as Davos Seaworthy did, who was a smuggler, not a soldier).

Jorah Mormont received a knighthood from King Robert I Baratheon, in recognition of his bravery during the [siege of Pyke](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Siege_of_Pyke).

According to Illyrio Mopatis, Jorah was anointed by the High Septon when he became a knight.

> **Illyrio** whispered to them. "Those three are Drogo’s bloodriders, there", he said. "By the pillar is
> Khal Moro, with his son Rhogoro. The man with the green beard is brother to the Archon of Tyrosh,
> and the man behind him is **Ser Jorah Mormont**".
> The last name caught Daenerys. **"A knight?**".
> "No less". Illyrio smiled through his beard. "**Anointed** with the seven oils **by the High Septon himself**".
> <sup><sub>**— George R. R. Martin, *A Game of Thrones*, Chapter 3 (Daenerys), Series: *A Song of Ice and Fire* - 1**</sub></sup>

It's customary to be anointed by a septon, but not always required either. The only requirement seems to be another knight to hear your vows, and witnesses are generally customary to add validity to the knighthood.

> “Hmpf.” The man Plummer rubbed his nose. “Any knight can make a knight, it is true, though it is more customary to stand a vigil and be anointed by a septon before taking your vows. Were there any witnesses to your dubbing?”
> <sup><sub>**- *The Hedge Knight***</sub></sup>

<sub><sup>Credit: see more detailed info on the different ways one can become a knight, and the intricacies in [this answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131327/73512), and how the procedure has changed over time in [this answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144714/73512), two *great* answers provided by @[Aegon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54887/aegon).</sup></sub>

Comment: OK, so when they sometimes said _*** is a Knight ointed by a Septon_ does not mean that there were an actual religious ceremony ? Or maybe there is different ways to validate knighthood ?

Comment: Wow, this is a better question than I'd realised. "*Eddard Stark himself was not a knight, because he proudly continued to worship the Old Gods of his ancestors*" - TIL.

Comment: @Bebs I edited my answer to add some more detail, context and a quote from the book, which will hopefully flesh it out somewhat more.

Comment: @Aegon Consider finding ways to make changes to the wikis. It'd be much more useful if the Wiki was accurate, from time to time :)

Comment: @GhotiandChips +1. Let's delete the now irrelevant comments. Also, as suggested before, you would be better off following the awoiaf wiki. It is accurate and up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't require a Septon to knight someone -- "Any knight can make a knight", according to the Dunk and Egg stories. It's true that there are fewer knights in the North, but there are some.

Comment: But, maybe I'm wrong, but Dunk lied... nobody really know if is a real knight.

Comment: @Bebs Dunk may have lied about being knighted by Ser Arlan, but everyone agrees that any knight can make a knight. He wasn't lying about that.