# Are there any other instances of an existing knight appointing another knight?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *Game of Thrones* S08E2 "A Knight of the Seven Kingdoms", in the scene where

> Jaime Lannister is knighting Brienne of Tarth, Jaime says it doesn't require a king to make one a knight. An existing knight can name another warrior a knight. Finally, Ser Jaime Lannister knights Brienne of Tarth and she is named "A Knight of the Seven Kingdoms".

Are there any instances in the books where an existing knight gave another warrior Knighthood by himself?

Comment: Do you count the prequel novellas as being included among "the books"? Because this a central plot point of "The Hedge Knight". Indeed, the title of the episode matches that of the collected novellas.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Yes, everything which is considered canon of Game of thrones Novels (I mean 5 novels starting from A Game of Thrones and ending with A Dance of the Dragons).

Comment: [Also read this page for additional examples of elevation to Knighthood](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Knight)

Comment: See also: [Who can Knight you so that the knighting 'sticks'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60937/21267)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. In the prequel novella "The Hedge Knight", the first of the three prequels included in the collection "A Knight of the Seven Kingdoms," it is established that any knight can make a knight.

> "Hmpf." The man Plummer rubbed his nose. **"Any knight can make a knight, it is true,** though it is more customary to stand a vigil and be anointed by a septon before taking your vows."

> "The lad has the truth of it," said Ser Lyonel Baratheon. "Do it, Ser Duncan. **Any knight can make a knight.**"

Indeed, this happens later in the story, when Ser Lyonel knights Raymund Fossoway.

---

This is also brought up briefly in *A Storm of Swords* when Arya meets Beric Dondarrion and his "Brotherhood without Banners":

> "Knights?" Clegane made the word a sneer. "Dondarrion's a knight, but the rest of you are the sorriest lot of outlaws and broken men I've ever seen. I shit better men than you."
>
> **"Any knight can make a knight,"** said the scarecrow that was Beric Dondarrion, "and every man you see before you has felt a sword upon his shoulder. We are the forgotten fellowship."

Comment: It’s also mentioned several times when the Brotherhood without Banners isintroduced.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, added an excerpt for that.

Comment: +1 This doesn't detract from your answer at all, but isn't it a key part of The Hedge Knight that it's unclear whether Ser Arlan of Pennytree knighted Duncan at all before dying? Duncan certainly claims he did, but he is not a disinterested party ;) We, the readers, have no proof either way.

Comment: @AndresF. True, we never see real proof of his knighthood. Personally I interpreted the story to be that Ser Arlan tried/wanted to knight Dunk, but was too old, frail, or forgetful to do it properly.